# drawing interleaved VBO with glDrawArrays

Tags: opengl, vbo

I'm currently using glDrawElements to render using multiple VBOs (vertex, color, texture, and index). I've found that very few vertices are shared, so I'd like to switch to glDrawArrays, and a single interleaved VBO.

I've been unable to find a clear example of 1) creating an interleaved VBO and adding a quad or tri to it (vert, color, texture), and 2) doing whatever is needed to draw it using glDrawArrays. What is the code for these two steps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
//init
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, new_array);
GLfloat data[] = { 
    0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f,
    0.f, 0.f, 100.f, 0.f, 1.f,
    0.f, 100.f, 100.f, 1.f, 1.f,
    0.f, 100.f, 100.f, 1.f, 1.f,
    0.f, 100.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f,
    0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f,
};
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// draw
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, new_array);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), ((char*)NULL)+3*sizeof(GLfloat) );
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

There is nothing particularly magic in this code. Just watch how:

- The data from the `data` array gets loaded: as is, all contiguous
- the stride for the various attributes is set to 5*sizeof(GLfloat), as this is what is in data: 3 floats for position and 2 for texcoord. Side note, you usually want this to be a power of 2, unlike here.
- the offset is computed from the start of the array. so since we store vertex first, the offset for vertex is 0. texcoord is stored after 3 floats of position data, so its offset is 3*sizeof(GLfloat).

I did not include color in there for a reason: they typically are stored as UNORMs, which makes for a messier initialization code. You need to store both GLfloat and GLubyte in the same memory chunk. At that point, structs can help if you want to do it in code, but it largely depends on where your data is ultimately coming from.

Comment: I hope its okay to comment so late after the post was made - but what is the reason for saying 'Side note, you usually want this to be a power of 2, unlike here.'?
If you are only using positions and tex coords, where would you fill out the extra data to make it a power of two ?  Also, do you mean the data array size should be a power of two or the stride in the function call?

Comment: It's really coming from past experience of people trying it out and finding it performs better with powers of two. You should not take this advice and run blindly with it, but rather verify it improves. The bottom of it is that any form of cache between the memory and the shader will likely work in power of two. Yes, the advice would be to pad the data, if required. Also if your dataset has any serious content, you usually have a lot of attributes, with flexibility as to which datatype to use. Developers pick wisely to "fit" in a power-of-two